# Twilio Voice Api - Is it possible to record message and play the record message in the a flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When a incoming call is received, I need to ask the caller to record a message. Then dial a number and play the recorded message when the receiver picks the call.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

*Note: replace Account SID, Auth Token, phone numbers, website address with your values.*

***Step 1.***

Answer incoming call and record message (`http://somewebsite.xyz/recordMessage.php`)

```
<?php    
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>

<Response>
    <Say>
        Please leave a message at the beep. 
        Press the star key when finished. 
    </Say>
    <Record 
        action="http://somewebsite.xyz/makeOutgoingCall.php" 
        maxLength="60"
        timeout="10"
        finishOnKey="*"
        />
    <Say>I did not receive a recording</Say>
</Response>
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record

Once the recording is finished Twilio will make a request to the 'action' URL and will pass the URL of the recording as a parameter named `RecordingUrl` ( `$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']` )

***Step 2.***

Make outgoing call ( `http://somewebsite.xyz/makeOutgoingCall.php`)

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>

<Response>
    <Say>Thank you for your message. Goodbye.</Say>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>

<?php
    // Include the Twilio PHP library
    require 'Services/Twilio.php';

    // Twilio REST API version
    $version = "2010-04-01";

    // Set our Account SID and AuthToken
    $sid = 'AC123';
    $token = 'abcd';

    // A phone number you have previously validated with Twilio
    $phonenumber = '4151234567';

    $recordingUrl = urlencode($_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']);

    // The URL Twilio will request when the call is answered            
    $twilioRequestUrl = "http://somewebsite.xyz/playRecordedMessage.php?RecordingUrl=".$recordingUrl;

    // Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);

    try {

        // Initiate a new outbound call
        $call = $client->account->calls->create(
            $phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
            '5101234567', // The number of the phone receiving call
            $twilioRequestUrl 
        );
        //echo 'Started call: ' . $call->sid;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request

***Step 3.***

Play the recorded message (`http://somewebsite.xyz/playRecordedMessage.php`).

```
<?php

    // and play the recording back, using the URL that Twilio posted
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Say>Take a listen to your message.</Say>
    <Play><?php echo $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; ?></Play>
    <Say>Goodbye.</Say>
</Response>
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml/play-mp3-for-caller

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play

Comment: Thanks for your reply with example. In step 2,  the caller should be on the call.  The receiver should hear the recorded message and talk to the caller. Removing hangup in the response will work?

Comment: Are you trying to screen calls? Does 'the receiver' always talks to the caller? If not, what do you do with the caller? Please update your question with the full user story.

Comment: The idea to get answer on a screening question from the caller  and play the answer to the receiver.

Comment: You can put the caller on a queue instead of hangup, and while the caller is waiting the receiver will hear the recording and after that you can connect the receiver to join the queue and talk to the caller. Modify step 2 and 3 with the Dial and Queue tags.